# Stripping off the zeros from a list containing a panda dataframe

Tags: list, pandas, dataframe, strip

i have a list 
[0,0,0, DataFrame1,0,0,DataFrame2,0,0, DataFrame3]

where Dataframe is a "Panda Dataframe".
now what i am trying to do is to strip of the '0' zeros (being integers). Is there any way i can do this  without using a loop. I tried to use set function, but it is not working with panda Dataframes.

My answer should resemble like this 
[ DateFrame1, DataFrame2, DataFrame3]

Comment: Try `[x for x in your_list if isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame)]` to keep only dataframes in list?

Comment: I have a problem though, i am checking this thing for about a million records. List comprehension in same as iterating over the previously defined list. There will be a possible speed overhead in my case. Is there any constant time solution possible for my  strip  function

Answer (score 0):

As @Zero, suggest in comment.

```
l = []
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(5,5))
l.append(0)
l.append(0)
l.append(df)
l.append(0)
l.append(0)
l.append(df)

print(l)
[0, 0,    0  1  2  3  4
 0  5  4  9  6  7
 1  9  9  2  7  3
 2  4  9  4  8  3
 3  4  6  2  5  5
 4  8  1  2  1  8, 0, 0,    0  1  2  3  4
 0  5  4  9  6  7
 1  9  9  2  7  3
 2  4  9  4  8  3
 3  4  6  2  5  5
 4  8  1  2  1  8]

[x for x in l if isinstance(x,pd.DataFrame)]
```

Output:

```
[   0  1  2  3  4
 0  5  4  9  6  7
 1  9  9  2  7  3
 2  4  9  4  8  3
 3  4  6  2  5  5
 4  8  1  2  1  8,    0  1  2  3  4
 0  5  4  9  6  7
 1  9  9  2  7  3
 2  4  9  4  8  3
 3  4  6  2  5  5
 4  8  1  2  1  8]
```